# How can I get a file's extension in PHP?

Tags: php, file-extension

This is a question you can read everywhere on the web with various answers:

```
$ext = end(explode('.', $filename));
$ext = substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1);
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
$ext = preg_replace('/^.*\.([^.]+)$/D', '$1', $filename);

$exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename);
$n    = count($exts)-1;
$ext  = $exts[$n];
```

etc.

However, there is always "the best way".

Comment: Source of question and answer: http://cowburn.info/2008/01/13/get-file-extension-comparison/

Comment: One more way to get ext is `strrchr($filename, '.');`

Comment: strrpos is the correct way (see my answer) but it needs an addition for the no-extension case.

Comment: Question is what you want with that info. Do you want to get the file extension to get the file type? That is not a good solution as it might be wrong.

Comment: Referenced in *[Start learning PHP—Useful resources for beginners and advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/articles/77378859/start-learning-php-useful-resources-for-beginners-and-advanced)*.

Answer (score 1980, accepted):

People from other scripting languages always think theirs is better because they have a built-in function to do that and not PHP (I am looking at Pythonistas right now :-)).

In fact, it does exist, but few people know it. Meet [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

This is built-in. `pathinfo()` can give you other information, such as canonical path, depending on the constant you pass to it.

Remember that if you want to be able to deal with non-ASCII characters, you need to set the locale first. For example:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

Also, note this doesn't take into consideration the file content or [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#MIME_header_fields), you only get the extension. But it's what you asked for.

Lastly, note that this works only for a file path, not a URL resources path, which is covered using PARSE_URL.

Comment: my pathinfo is disabled then short way to extract  extension string ?

Comment: @khizaransari You should look for another hosting provider, the one you got is stupid. Really, I mean it. There is _no reason whatsoever_ to disable this function. Tell them that. As a workaround: `function get_ext($fname){ return substr($fname, strrpos($fname, ".") + 1); }` Make sure the file has an extension though, it may do anything when you pass a path as argument!

Comment: I have a problem with this example - it doesn't work for names like ".............doc", any ideas why ?

Comment: my idea of PHP compared to python changed completely now that I know about this function :O

Comment: @e-satis but its not working in one scenario in my application, Like some times I am getting a URL in following format , `www.domain.com/image.php?id=123&idlocation=987&number=01`  to download the images since this uRL does not have the image name or extention the pathifo()  is failling to give us the image extension . SO what should be done please!!! help me

Comment: It's really not fair that I did not waste as much as some of the other people here, and instead found this answer and solved my problem quickly.

Comment: This is NOT a secure solution. If someone uploaded to your endpoint without using a browser they could spoof the extension. For example: pathinfo('image.jpg.spoofed',PATHINFO_EXTENSION) returns 'spoofed' !! It does not check actual file body since it doesn't take the file path, and it does not verify its result with a MimeType Map. You should ensure the value you receive from this is in fact a valid type by querying http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.txt or by checking your own MimeType Map.

Comment: **BE CAREFULL!!!!!   THIS IS NOT SAFE FUNCTION !!!** read other answers!

Comment: **This is a very slow way** to do it, pathinfo does a lot more than what you're looking for and it's all discarded on return. I added another answer with some time measurements.

Answer (score 194):

[`pathinfo()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$path_info = pathinfo('/foo/bar/baz.bill');

echo $path_info['extension']; // "bill"
```

Comment: Since PHP 5.5 -> `echo pathinfo('/foo/bar/baz.bill')['extension'];`

Comment: This even works on this level (Twitter json): $ext = pathinfo($result->extended_entities->media[0]->video_info->variants[1]->url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Answer (score 126):

Example URL: **`http://example.com/myfolder/sympony.mp3?a=1&b=2#XYZ`**

A) *Don't use suggested unsafe [**`PATHINFO`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php#example-2610)*:

```
pathinfo($url)['dirname']    'http://example.com/myfolder'
pathinfo($url)['basename']   'sympony.mp3?a=1&b=2#XYZ'         // <------- BAD !!
pathinfo($url)['extension']  'mp3?a=1&b=2#XYZ'                 // <------- BAD !!
pathinfo($url)['filename']   'sympony'
```

B) Use [PARSE_URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#refsect1-function.parse-url-examples):

```
parse_url($url)['scheme']    'http'
parse_url($url)['host']      'example.com'
parse_url($url)['path']      '/myfolder/sympony.mp3'
parse_url($url)['query']     'aa=1&bb=2'
parse_url($url)['fragment']  'XYZ'
```

BONUS: View [all native PHP examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php/26944636#26944636)

Comment: This answer covers everything eg. a file like `foo_folder/foo-file.jpg?1345838509` will fail miserably with just `pathinfo`, thanx

Comment: Not completely on-topic, but it sure did solve my problem!

Comment: Don't forget nothing! `parse_url` is for URL and `pathinfo` is for file path.

Comment: What do you mean "forget path info"? You use it in the solution!

Comment: @AutumnLeonard He doesn't, he just showed the differences between pathinfo and parse_url.

Comment: for those who have problem with file names like Webp.net-resizeimage_%288%29.png?1547034073 where we have multiple dots you can use php end() function to get last item of array than includes the file format

Comment: Naturally, you shouldn't use pathinfo with a url.

Comment: `pathinfo()` would be the best solution if used on `$_FILES` (POST upload). So it works well, as long that it is used correctly. If the original question was about how to get an extension out from an URL with query string parameters, then yes, in that case your solution would have been correct.

Comment: Parse URL doesn't get the file extension which is what the question asks. The filename is already acquired in the question so while a good comparison is not a good answer.

Comment: It all depends on what you know about the input. If you KNOW it's a local path with a filename, parse_url() is pointless. If it's an URL, sure, get the path fragment first. Also, if it's a whole book about an URL, strip the rest of the book first, then parse the URL. You see where I'm going. pathinfo is not unsafe, unless you misuse it by giving it something unexpected, like a whole URL.

Comment: Good point, but the question was for the file's extension. This answer + that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61079134/2444812 seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 72):

There is also [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo):

```
$file = new SplFileInfo($path);
$ext  = $file->getExtension();
```

Often you can write better code if you pass such an object around instead of a string. Your code is more speaking then. Since PHP 5.4 this is a one-liner:

```
$ext  = (new SplFileInfo($path))->getExtension();
```

Comment: Fantastic, Its Objects all the way down :)

Comment: Please be aware that `->getExtension()` is available in SplFileInfo since PHP 5.3.6.

Comment: @matthias: Please be aware that SPL can be disabled in PHP versions that predate the PHP 5.3.0 release. If you're still not running PHP 5.3 but 5.2 or lower, this answer most likely did not fit for stable code. Otherwise you can stabilize your code by requiring a specific PHP version and otherwise bail out.

Comment: @hakre While you're correct in saying it "can be disabled in versions predating 5.3.0", the SPL extension is nevertheless compiled in by default as of PHP 5.0.0. So this comment makes indeed sense for people forced to use PHP 5.2 or lower and don't want to resign using specific SPL classes.

Comment: `$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` or `$ext = pathinfo($file)['extension']` are better one-liners.

Comment: This answer is useful when you want an extension from a simple string

Answer (score 54):

### Do it faster!

In other words, if you only work with a filename, please stop using pathinfo.

I mean, sure if you have a *full pathname*, pathinfo makes sense because it's smarter than just finding dots: the path can contain dots and filename itself may have none. So in this case, considering an input string like `d:/some.thing/myfile`, pathinfo and other fully equipped methods are a good choice.

But if all you have is a *filename*, with no path, it's simply pointless to make the system work a lot more than it needs to. And this can give you **a 10x speed boost**.

Here's a quick speed test:

```php
/*   387 ns */ function method1($s) {return preg_replace("/.*\./","",$s);} // edge case problem
/*   769 ns */ function method2($s) {preg_match("/\.([^\.]+)$/",$s,$a);return $a[1];}
/*    67 ns */ function method3($s) {$n = strrpos($s,"."); if($n===false) return "";return substr($s,$n+1);}
/*   175 ns */ function method4($s) {$a = explode(".",$s);$n = count($a); if($n==1) return "";return $a[$n-1];}
/*   731 ns */ function method5($s) {return pathinfo($s, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);}
/*   732 ns */ function method6($s) {return (new SplFileInfo($s))->getExtension();}

//  All measured on Linux; it will be vastly different on Windows
```

Those nanosecond values will obviously differ on each system, but they give a clear picture about proportions. `SplFileInfo` and `pathinfo` are great fellas, but for this kind of job it's simply not worth it to wake them up. For the same reason, `explode()` is considerably faster than regex. Very simple tools tend to beat more sophisticated ones.

#### Conclusion

This seems to be the Way of the Samurai:

```php
function fileExtension($name) {
    $n = strrpos($name, '.');
    return ($n === false) ? '' : substr($name, $n+1);
}
```

*Remember this is for simple filenames only. If you have paths involved, stick to pathinfo or deal with the dirname separately.*

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. It's always nice to find those well-researched newer answers on older questions. Saves time figuring out what techniques might be outdated.

Comment: strrpos method might need another check for this case with no extension "filename."

Comment: @ungalcrys in that case, substr will take an empty portion so the extension itself will be "", just as it should.

Comment: @dkellner care to also benchmark `$info = new SplFileInfo('test.png');$info->getExtension();`?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen The server I used for this benchmark now gets totally different results. Probably there was a php update too, but for sure it's a stronger hardware. Anyway, while phpinfo is now approximately the same as method1, splFileInfo is just as slow, even a little bit slower. I think I'm gonna update the charts.

Comment: This seems to be an optimization that fits better in the C implementation of pathinfo or some other standard library function? In general I'd like to make the remark that if you have no performance scaling issues, have not done any profiling and have not reached the conclusion that this is an important culprit it's probably premature optimization to write this function yourself. Also, what happens if `there.are.multiple.dots.in.your.filename`?

Comment: @TimStrijdhorst - it should work as expected with several dots. Also, it's very important to write code with speed in mind.

Comment: Nice answer. For completeness, I'd show the speed of `basename()` to see if it could still be faster to avoid path info or spl if you have to start with a full path. Perhaps also include `realpath` as it might indicate pathinfo or spl worthy if you suddenly need 3 operations if you get me. Also like to point out that all your benchmarks are wrapped in a function when some do not need the function overhead but others such as the `strrpos` method require function wrappers and that in itself slows it down. Pathinfo may be faster because it needs no function wrapper to be easily repeated.

Comment: @Brad: extra tests are always welcome. But for filenames with no path, there's no need to use basename, and realpath only works for existing files (which is not necessarily the case - it could be a moment before you even create the file), so these are different concerns. Yes I see your point btw, but that's why I made it clear that this is only about filenames.

Comment: I also appreciate well researched responses, and there are times when speed is really important. But... the 10x speed boost you're talking about here (which is probably less now) is roughly {a millionth of a second} vs {a ten-millionth of a second}. If a script processes 1,000 filenames, the savings of using your fastest solution would amount to less than 1 millisecond. I ended up on this page because I'm writing a script that will process 30-40 files in a cron job. The time savings would be literally worthless. Readability and reliability are often more important than speed.

Comment: @davidreedernst - "fileExtension" is quite readable. Also, for 50-100 iterations you don't need super speed. Imagine a logfile with 15M items.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @YourCommonSense : actually, early optimization is very important and it's a shame not to write code with performance and security in mind, from step 0. So no: in fact omitting fine tuning in early stages / low level routines IS the root of many problems. It's the reason you still see spinning loading animations in 2023.

Comment: No, it's actually premature optimization is the reason why I am seeing spinning loading animations in 2023. Because people do follow such pointless suggestions instead of optimizing real bottlenecks.

Comment: I know this looks like a debate but for me there is no benefit of convincing you. Now either you gain information from above or you don't - that's your decision.

Comment: Strpos returns the first occurence of our wanted char, isn't it? Then method 3 is bad, since some simple file names often have dots in them. I think the one with explode and taking the last item in the resulting array is the best choice.

Comment: @DanielWu luckily, that's no strpos there.

Comment: @dkellner Whoa... I missed the extra r. I have used PHP for years and I have never known about strrpos :-D

Comment: @DanielWu To be honest, it's more php's mistake than yours; also, these strxxx functions come from the Ancient Realm Of C where readability meant a completely different thing (and 80 characters made up a whole screen width and there was no syntax highlighting and we had to find a phone booth to call home when we were late, yada yada). It would totally make sense to call these bad guys strFirstPos / strLastPos - I'm not sure why php never introduced some aliases with unified naming. Then again, we survived this one, we survive everything :)

Comment: Yeah strrpos is so untuitive and hard to notice. On a glance, most people will think it's a same function as strpos.

Answer (score 25):

As long as it does not contain a path you can also use:

```
array_pop(explode('.', $fname))
```

Where `$fname` is a name of the file, for example: `my_picture.jpg`.
And the outcome would be: `jpg`

Comment: @Why this have 3 downvotes? its giving proper result. Please explain

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just not the best way to do it. Upvoted for a bit of balance.

Comment: This is the best way, when you need the real extension and filename may have multiple .'s in it, like user uploaded photos in my case.

Comment: This fails if the filename has no extension. Try passing in "myfile" and it will return "myfile". The correct return value is an empty string as the extension in this use case.

Comment: This is wrong in that array_pop() will throw a notice because it takes a pointer as its parameter.

Answer (score 24):

[*Bite code*'s response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-can-i-get-a-files-extension-in-php/173876#173876) is the correct way to determine the file extension.

Alternatively, instead of relying on a files extension, you could use the [fileinfo](https://www.php.net/fileinfo) to determine the files MIME type.

Here's a simplified example of processing an image uploaded by a user:

```
// Code assumes necessary extensions are installed and a successful file upload has already occurred

// Create a FileInfo object
$finfo = new FileInfo(null, '/path/to/magic/file');

// Determine the MIME type of the uploaded file
switch ($finfo->file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], FILEINFO_MIME)) {
    case 'image/jpg':
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    break;

    case 'image/png':
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    break;

    case 'image/gif':
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is the ONLY correct answer. I don't understand why people voted-up others. Yes, this approach demands more efforts from developer but it boosts performance(although little, but it does). Please refer  [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php#47867).

Comment: @Bhavik : In some cases we may only need the file extension, they about the mime type check. But the actual question is about file extension, not file type. So this is NOT the best answer for this question. (yet an answer)

Comment: A filename doesn't even mean that the file exists, so anything relying on the contents is wrong in the first place. Then, even if there's an actual file, it's a lot slower to open it than to just know the name, and also you can't even be sure you have the rights to access the file itself. Not to mention locking and other potential problems. So no. It's not the best answer, far from it actually.

Answer (score 14):

**1)** If you are using **(PHP 5 >= 5.3.6)**
you can use **[SplFileInfo::getExtension](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php) — Gets the file extension**

Example code

```
<?php

$info = new SplFileInfo('test.png');
var_dump($info->getExtension());

$info = new SplFileInfo('test.tar.gz');
var_dump($info->getExtension());

?>
```

This will output

```
string(3) "png"
string(2) "gz"
```

**2)** Another way of getting the extension if you are using **(PHP 4 >= 4.0.3, PHP 5)** is [**pathinfo**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Example code

```
<?php

$ext = pathinfo('test.png', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
var_dump($ext);

$ext = pathinfo('test.tar.gz', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
var_dump($ext);

?>
```

This will output

```
string(3) "png"
string(2) "gz"
```

// EDIT: removed a bracket

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes it's useful to not to use `pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`. For example:

```
$path = '/path/to/file.tar.gz';

echo ltrim(strstr($path, '.'), '.'); // tar.gz
echo pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // gz
```

Also note that `pathinfo` fails to handle some non-ASCII characters (usually it just suppresses them from the output). In extensions that usually isn't a problem, but it doesn't hurt to be aware of that caveat.

Comment: @e-satis: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) they are two extensions: *The UNIX-like filesystems use a different model without the segregated extension metadata. The dot character is just another character in the main filename, and filenames can have multiple extensions, usually representing nested transformations, such as files.tar.gz*.

Comment: And if we have dot in the product name?
Ex : `test.19-02-2014.jpeg`

Comment: This will fail with /root/my.folder/my.css `ltrim(strrchr($PATH, '.'),'.')` works like pathinfo, but without tokenizing everything.

Answer (score 11):

### Sorry... "Short Question; But NOT Short Answer"

**Example 1 for PATH**

```
$path = "/home/ali/public_html/wp-content/themes/chicken/css/base.min.css";
$name = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$ext  = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
printf('<hr> Name: %s <br> Extension: %s', $name, $ext);
```

**Example 2 for URL**

```
$url = "//www.example.com/dir/file.bak.php?Something+is+wrong=hello";
$url = parse_url($url);
$name = pathinfo($url['path'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$ext  = pathinfo($url['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
printf('<hr> Name: %s <br> Extension: %s', $name, $ext);
```

Output of example 1:

```
Name: base.min
Extension: css
```

Output of example 2:

```
Name: file.bak
Extension: php
```

### References

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php
2. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php
3. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way to get file extension in PHP is to use PHP's built-in function [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
$file_ext = pathinfo('your_file_name_here', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo ($file_ext); // The output should be the extension of the file e.g., png, gif, or html
```

Answer (score 10):

**The "best" way depends on the context and what you are doing with that file extension.**
However,

[pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) in general is the best when you consider all the angles.

```
pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
```

It is not the fastest, but it is fast enough. It is easy to read, easy to remember and reuse everywhere. Anyone can understand it at a glance and remove PATHINFO_EXT flag if they need more info about the file.

❌ [strrpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) method. described in several answers is faster yes but requires additional safety checks which, in turn, requires you to wrap it inside a function, to make it easily reusable.
Then you must take the function with you from project to project or look it up.
Wrapping it in a function call with extra checks also makes it slower and if you need any other info about the file you now have other methods to call and at that point, you lose the speed advantage anyway whilst having a solution that's harder to read.
The potential for speed is there but is not worth it unless you need to address such a bottleneck.

❌ I'd also rule out any ideas using [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr), [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode), and most other manual manipulations for the same reasons mentioned above.

❌[SplFileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) is very cool but takes up much more brain space  with a lot of interfaces that you no doubt waste time learning only to look them up again next time. I'd only use it in specific cases where you will find the extra interfaces worth someone learning Spl when they come back to add/edit your code later.

❌ I would not consider [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) at all as any regex function in PHP is on average 3 times slower than any other function, is harder to read, and is in most cases can easily be done with something simpler. Regex is powerful and it has its place in those specific situations where it can replace several method calls and condition checks in one line.
Getting a file extension this way is like using an anvil to hammer in a nail.

---

While of course "the best" would come down to public opinion, I'd argue that other methods are only "the best" in specialized cases.

For example, if you just want to check for a specific type then I wouldn't use any of the suggested methods as [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) would be the fastest case insensitive comparison to use.

```
if (stripos('/here/is/sOme.fiLe.PdF', '.pdf', -4) !== false )
{
    //its a pdf file
}
```

But again pathinfo would still be nicer to read and probably worth the performance cost.

**But what about https://ome.Com.///lica.ted?URLS ?**

Extracting paths from URLs is a separate concern that is outside the scope of the question and will require an extra step in any case where a simple one-time string comparison won't do.

Answer (score 9):

You can try also this (it works on PHP 5.* and 7):

```
$info = new SplFileInfo('test.zip');
echo $info->getExtension(); // ----- Output -----> zip
```

Tip: it returns an empty string if the file doesn't have an extension

Answer (score 6):

```
substr($path, strrpos($path, '.') + 1);
```

Comment: This will fail with /root/my.folder/my.css

Comment: This must work correctly: substr($path, strrpos($path,'.')+1);

Note: this method is faster than any other solutions above. Try a benchmark using our own script.

Comment: It's very fast but has a serious problem with files having no extension at all. It would strip the first character in such cases. See my solution above (Ctrl+F and type samurai); almost the same, with this tiny difference. So yes, the method is indeed cool and super fast but you should watch out for edge cases.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example. Suppose $filename is "example.txt",

```
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.', -1), strlen($filename));
```

So $ext will be ".txt".

Answer (score 6):

[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is an array. We can check **directory name, file name, extension**, etc.:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('test.png');

echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

A quick fix would be something like this.

```
// Exploding the file based on the . operator
$file_ext = explode('.', $filename);

// Count taken (if more than one . exist; files like abc.fff.2013.pdf
$file_ext_count = count($file_ext);

// Minus 1 to make the offset correct
$cnt = $file_ext_count - 1;

// The variable will have a value pdf as per the sample file name mentioned above.
$file_extension = $file_ext[$cnt];
```

Comment: Why not just to use php built in function for the purpose http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php instead of using long code

Comment: Besides Shahbaz's point you can also just do `$file_ext = end(explode('.', $filename));` to do everything in this answer in a single line instead of four.

Comment: @Amelia What if you have `.tar.gz`. It will not work, so if you need to get full of extension use such as `ltrim(strstr($filename, '.'), '.');` to get full of extension instead uncorrectly as `gz`.

Answer (score 5):

IMO, this is the best way if you have filenames like name.name.name.ext (ugly, but it sometimes happens):

```
$ext     = explode('.', $filename); // Explode the string
$my_ext  = end($ext); // Get the last entry of the array

echo $my_ext;
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that the `pathinfo()` and `SplFileInfo` solutions works well for standard files on the local file system, but you can run into difficulties if you're working with remote files as URLs for valid images may have a `#` (fragment identifiers) and/or `?` (query parameters) at the end of the URL, which both those solutions will (incorrect) treat as part of the file extension.

I found this was a reliable way to use `pathinfo()` on a URL after first parsing it to strip out the unnecessary clutter after the file extension:

```
$url_components = parse_url($url); // First parse the URL
$url_path = $url_components['path']; // Then get the path component
$ext = pathinfo($url_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // Then use pathinfo()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try also this:

```
 pathinfo(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
```

Answer (score 4):

In one line:

```
pathinfo(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH),PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `substr($path, strrpos($path,'.')+1);`. It is the fastest method of all compares.

@Kurt Zhong already answered.

Let's check the comparative result here: https://eval.in/661574

Comment: Nope. It is not the fastest AND it will give you a little surprise if you call it with a filename that has no extension.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: This has already been answered much better by Subodh back in August.

Comment: This was already suggested back in 2008.   Please only post an answer if you have something unique and valuable to give.  Redundant content only wastes the time of researchers and bloats Stack Overflow pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all file extensions in a particular folder and do operations with a specific file extension:

```
<?php
    $files = glob("abc/*.*"); // abc is the folder all files inside folder
    //print_r($files);
    //echo count($files);
    for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++):
         $extension = pathinfo($files[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
         $ext[] = $extension;
         // Do operation for particular extension type
         if($extension=='html'){
             // Do operation
         }
    endfor;
    print_r($ext);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ltrim(strstr($file_url, '.'), '.')
```

> this is the best way if you have filenames like name.name.name.ext (ugly, but it sometimes happens

Comment: To me this doesn't make sense. It only removes everything that comes before the first . (dot) and returns everything afterwards. Which means that if you have something like:  **www.indexpage.com/videos/phpExtensions.mp4?v/345** your proposed method will return **indexpage.com/videos/phpExtensions.mp4?v/345** and that's not a file extension. Or did I miss something?

Comment: yeah, this doesn't work how he suggests at all.

Answer (score 2):

`$ext = preg_replace('/^.*\.([^.]+)$/D', '$1', $fileName);`

preg_replace approach we using regular expression search and replace. In preg_replace function first parameter is pattern to the search, second parameter $1 is a reference to whatever is matched by the first (.*) and third parameter is file name.

Another way, we can also use strrpos to find the position of the last occurrence of a ‘.’ in a file name and increment that position by 1 so that it will explode string from (.)

`$ext = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, '.') + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for speed (such as in a router), you probably don't want to tokenize everything. Many other answers will fail with `/root/my.folder/my.css`

```
ltrim(strrchr($PATH, '.'),'.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the "best way" is debatable, I believe this is the best way for a few reasons:

```
function getExt($path)
{
    $basename = basename($path);
    return substr($basename, strlen(explode('.', $basename)[0]) + 1);
}
```

1. It works with multiple parts to an extension, eg `tar.gz`
2. Short and efficient code
3. It works with both a filename and a complete path

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was looking for that.

```php
<?php

$url = 'http://example.com/myfolder/sympony.mp3?a=1&b=2#XYZ';
$tmp = @parse_url($url)['path'];
$ext = pathinfo($tmp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

var_dump($ext);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried one simple solution it might help to someone else to get just filename from the URL which having get parameters

```
<?php

$path = "URL will be here";
echo basename(parse_url($path)['path']);

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
str_replace('.', '', strrchr($file_name, '.'))
```

for a quick extension retrieval (if you know for sure your file name has one).

Answer (score -1):

### Don't trust the file extension from the file path.

**You must be careful when assuming that a file extension reflects what the file contains.** A malicious script can easily be hidden under another file extension.

**You can detect the real file extension (from reading inside the file), with [`mime_content_type($filePath)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)**, if your [PHP module mod_mime_magic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime_magic.html) is on.

This will give you the accurate [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#MIME_header_fields) of the file, from which you can easily resolve the extension with a simple function like:

```php
/**
 * Get the file extension for a given mime type.
 *
 * @param string $mimeType
 * @return string|false the file extension or false in case of failure
 */
function getExtension (string $mimeType): string|false {
  $extensions = [
      'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
      'image/png' => 'png',
      'image/gif' => 'gif',
      'image/webp' => 'webp',
      'image/svg' => 'svg',
      'image/svg+xml' => 'svg',
      'application/json' => 'json',
      'application/pdf' => 'pdf',
      'application/zip' => 'zip',
      'application/x-zip-compressed' => 'zip',
      'text/xml' => 'xml',
      ... // NOT EXHAUSTIVE LIST.
  ];

  return $extensions[$mimeType] ?? false;
}
```

In addition, in some cases, there is no extension in the file path, and it is therefore impossible to know its extension from `pathinfo($file->tmp_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`. In that case, `mime_content_type` function will still succeed.

Comment: It's not that simple. And blindly trusting the mime type can do more harm than good. How can you be sure that a "malicious" script is not "hidden" under another mime type as well? If a file both an image and a php script, what extension would be "real" for it?

Comment: Your answer seems redundant and potentially dangerous in the context of current question. Yes, it's a good idea to validate files on upload (but checking the file extension is more important still). But using mime for the files that's already on your server is redundant

Comment: Quoting the PHP module content: "This module determines the MIME type of files in the same way the Unix file(1) command works: it looks at the first few bytes of the file. It is intended as a "second line of defense" for cases that mod_mime can't resolve." -> I think this is one of the safest ways because it tries to read the file. Before blindly accepting the file on the server, I think it's still a good idea to check the mime and reject (delete from the server) if extension not allowed. This may still not be bulletproof, but it's a second layer of protection for not much effort.

Comment: The problem is, this answer is misplaced. The question has nothing to do with file uploads. It's *just* about getting a file ext from a filename.

Comment: the question is "How to get a file's extension in PHP?" obviously not stating it should be from file name - but I don't care. this may be useful to some other users