# Change file extension

Tags: php

How do I change a files file-extension name in PHP?

For example: `$filename='234230923_picture.bmp'` and I want the extension to change to `jpg`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just replace it with regexp:

```
$filename = preg_replace('"\.bmp$"', '.jpg', $filename);
```

You can also extend this code to remove other image extensions, not just `bmp`:

```
$filename = preg_replace('"\.(bmp|gif)$"', '.jpg', $filename);
```

Comment: Using slow regex for such simple task?

Answer (score 26):

```
$newname = basename($filename, ".bmp").".jpg";
rename($filename, $newname);
```

Remember that if the file is a bmp file, changing the suffix won't change the format :)

Answer (score 3):

[`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) the file, substituting the new extension.

Answer (score 3):

Not using regex (like the basename example), but allowing multiple extension possibilities (like the regex example):

```
$newname = str_replace(array(".bmp", ".gif"), ".jpg", $filename);
rename($filename, $newname);
```

Of course any simple replace operation, while less expensive then regex, will also replace a .bmp in the middle of the filename.

As mentioned, this isn't going to change the format of a image file. To do that you would need to use a graphics library.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to rename the file https://www.php.net/rename and this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php to get the basename of the file and other extension info..