# Change URL with PHP, slice

Tags: php, url, slice

I have a url that ends with _s.jpg.  The URL is set to a variable, and it called later on.  Before it's called I need to slice the URL and remove _s.jpg and add _o.jpg.

```
$img_src = $data['picture'];
```

This returns my url

```
http://photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/416968_4827318927507_851357969_s.jpg
```

I need the $img_src URL changed and then put into a new variable $new_img_src

I know I can do it with jQuery, but I need it done in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) for simplicity, or [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) for asserting the structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [change file extension in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724612/change-file-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$new_img_src = str_replace('_s.jpg', '_o.jpg', $data['picture']);
```

this ought to work...