# Get Php file/images extension

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a images file extension and add some random number. **Like**  348678423.jpeg, 343344343.jpg, 32434343.gif, 3434343.png etc..

**So following is my php code:**

```
function getExtension($str)
{
     $i = strrpos($str,".");
 if (!$i) { return ""; }
 $l = strlen($str) - $i;
 $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
 return $ext;
}
  @$extension = getExtension($file);
   $extension = strtolower($extension);
  $image_named_uniq = uniqid().'.'.$extension;
```

But when i echo this variable **$image_named_uniq** it's just show the random number, Like: **50aa5a2e0f425.** It's should be show **50aa5a2e0f425.jpg** etc..

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the file type in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740406/how-to-get-the-file-type-in-php). What's the likelyhood of a file extension question never having been asked in stackoverflow before? Look at the related section.

Comment: use `pathinfo()` **pathinfo() returns information about path: either an associative array or a string, depending on options.** it's better than to write you own implementation. [pathinfo.link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer posted by @jereon is correct, and the easiest way to do this.

However, if you would like to extract more information about the file without using explode and end, you can simply use the PHP built in `pathinfo()` function.

Reference: [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
<?php
    $path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

    echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
    echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
    echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
    echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

This will return

```
/www/htdocs/inc
lib.inc.php
php
lib.inc
```

As `$filename` is an array, you need to loop through it in order to read it into `pathinfo()`. This can be done very easily using a foreach loop like so:

```
// Loop through the filenames array
foreach($filename as $value){
    // Retrieve the path parts of each individual file
    $path_parts[] = pathinfo($value);
}

// Write out the path parts array
print_r($path_parts);
```

Comment: It's show error message: Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\Software\Installed\xampp\htdocs\Classified-website\user\content\uploader.php on line 47

Comment: @Shibbir What are you passing into the `pathinfo()` function? It is obviously an array

Comment: I passing my variable called $filename which is $filename = $_FILES['images']['name'];

Comment: @Shibbir Yes, that is an array. You need to loop through using a foreach. Would you like me to demonstrate?

Comment: @Shibbir Answer edited, you will need to amend what I have posted but it should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 5):

If you just need the extension:

```
echo end(explode('.', $str));
```

Comment: I would also recommend using `strtolower` on the `$str`

Comment: For better performance use `$ext = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1);`

Comment: @jeroen Thanks for your reply. I need to echo the random filename with extension. Like: 3432434.jpg.

Comment: @BenCarey no it is not, the easiest way `$data=$pathinfo($path);echo $data['extension'];` not to mention that is pointless to rewrite functionality that you already have.

Comment: @Nikola I agree about rewriting functionality being pointless, but, this is a pretty easy method to understand for a novice programmer. Personally I would use `pathinfo` as I have stated in my answer :-)

Comment: Look When I echo end(explode('.', $str)); then i get 2 error message.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: str in D:\Software\Installed\xampp\htdocs\Classified-website\user\content\uploader.php on line 44

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in D:\Software\Installed\xampp\htdocs\Classified-website\user\content\uploader.php on line 44

Comment: Spoon-fed debugging service!

Comment: @Mike B Next question is why the value gets displayed instead of appended to the ID...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the extension

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
echo $path_parts['extension'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [pathinfo()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php). Note that the result is based on the filename and no introspection on the file is performed (eg. the image `logo.jpg` renamed to `logo.php` will result in a `.php` file extension. Use [the fileinfo extension](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) if you want to get the filetype by it's contents)