# What PHP function will give me the type of file?

Tags: php, file, types

I'm getting a file with "file_get_contents", there is any PHP Function that will give me the type of the file? In this example "jpg".

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents("/path/to/image.jpg");
```

Please give me some clues.

Best Regards,

Comment: Duuuuplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php

Comment: **Note:** the **type of file** and the **file extension** are completely different concepts. A .php file might be renamed to .jpg, it would look like a jpg file, but the file type is still php. Whereas you can find the **file extension** using `pathinfo()`, the file type is best found using `fileinfo` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo) like this:

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // jpg
```

Note that since this fetch the extension from the filename, it can easily be manipulated. You should use a function like [getimagesize](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to determine if a file is a real image.

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is **extension**.

```
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

This is an exact duplicate of [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php) though, try searching a bit better next time.