# How to get the file extension?

Tags: php, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract a file extension in PHP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

For example if i have a path (generated by my torrent_info_gen)-

**Driver Genius Professional Edition 10.0.0.526/Driver Genius Professional Edition 10.0.0.526.exe**

How should i get the extension of the file in the path!
I also want to have the path and filename to be shown differently in this way:

**Path: (Path of the file)**

**Filename: (Name of the file)**

**Extension: (Extension of the file)**

Can someone help me!
Please!!!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mark Cidade: Though the question title implies only an extension, they are looking for more information. not exactly a duplicate, only 1/3 of their question is answered in the other post.

Comment: There's enough information in the other page (i.e., link to pathinfo docs) to answer this question.

Comment: Then why ask a question SO? I mean the docs cover this perfectly... Oh yea, reference; so others with the same problem can have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
    $str = "Driver Genius Professional Edition 10.0.0.526/Driver Genius Professional Edition 10.0.0.526.exe";

    $info  = pathinfo($str);

    var_dump($info['dirname']);
    var_dump($info['filename']);
    var_dump($info['extension']);
```

Gives:

```
string 'Driver Genius Professional Edition 10.0.0.526' (length=45)
string 'Driver Genius Professional Edition 10.0.0.526' (length=45)
string 'exe' (length=3)
```

Comment: Just fair warning, `filename` is only applicable >= 5.2.0, and can omit the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

```
$info = pathinfo($filename);

echo "Path: ".$info['dirname'];
echo "Filename: ".$info['basename'];
echo "Extension: ".$info['extension'];
```

Documentation on [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Comment: @Divya: You're very welcome, and welcome to SO. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

the obvious solution is already posted so here is smthing different

```
      $file = 'C:/foo/bar/do.exe';
    echo dirname($file);
    $ext = array_pop(explode('.',$file));
    $filename = basename($file);
$filenameWithoutExtension = basename($file,'.' . $ext);

    echo $ext;
    echo $filename;
```