# PHP - Parsing a string

Tags: php, string

I would like to know how to parse the text of a file name so it keeps the extension.

so `someimage.jpg` would become `.jpg`. This is so I can change the file name but leave the extension.

Thanks.

Comment: `*yawn*` exact duplicate of zillion similar questions like [How to get the file extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841223/how-to-get-the-file-extension)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and pass the `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` flag to get the file extension. You need to add the dot yourself as the function leaves it out:

```
$oldname = 'someimage.jpg';
$ext = pathinfo($oldname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
rename($oldname, 'thisimage.' . $ext);
```

Comment: I assume the downvote must have come from none other than the Colonel himself. Don't worry, I was **expecting** it :)

Comment: @nikic sure, they are. always greedy to snatch some rep points rather than close duplicated question.

Comment: @Col: This is already being discussed on meta and meta is the only place there a decision may be provoked. Downvoting answers is no good, instead convince people on meta that a) rep on duplicate question shall be dropped (the idea is quite popular, actually) and/or b) rep is given for finding duplicates and/or voting to close as duplicate.