# Get extension from filename like variable

Tags: php, file-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

I have a variable `$filename="filename.ext"` or `$filename="filena.m.e.ext"` or so on.. How can i extract the extension (here `ext`) from the variable / string? The variable may change or may have more than one dots.. In that case, i want to get the part after the last dot..

Answer (score 58, accepted):

see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php) :

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: which is faster? ($imgname, strlen($imgname) - 4, 4); or pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: @zPuls3 `pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` is way more exact because of different possible extension lengths.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the path info interrogation.

```
$info = pathinfo($file);
```

where

```
$info['extension']
```

contains the extension

Answer (score 4):

you could define a function like this:

```
function get_file_extension($filename)
{
    /*
     * "." for extension should be available and not be the first character
     * so position should not be false or 0.
     */
    $lastDotPos = strrpos($fileName, '.');
    if ( !$lastDotPos ) return false;
    return substr($fileName, $lastDotPos+1);
}
```

or you could use the [Spl_FileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php) object built into PHP

Comment: +1'ed for reminding of this. I always feel I don't use SPL as much as I could (and should).

Comment: +1 because this also work for URLs.

Comment: well cool, but it's better to check from the end to the start! because the dot is almost in the end in general. with a loop, when we reach first dot, we substr ! Also is that faster better then pathinfo()? there is the fact that it return an array (different data) more computation to do! but what about pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)?? does this compute all the data, or just execute a one info getting method

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a regular expression:

```
preg_match('/\.([^\.]+)$/', $filename);
```

You can test it out [here](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php) to see if it gets you the result you want given your input.

Comment: I don't really care for your answer as there are a couple of native options for this but +1'ed for the nifty online reg-ex tester!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, ie with explode() or with a preg_match and others.

But the way I do this is [with pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$path_info = pathinfo($filename);

echo $path_info['extension'], "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could explode the string using ., then take the last array item:

```
$filename = "file.m.e.ext";
$filenameitems = explode(".", $filename);

echo $filenameitems[count($filenameitems) - 1]; // .ext
// or echo $filenameitem[-1];
```

Comment: What about `filename.tar.gz`?