# Changing the filename of the uploaded file from 'filename' to 'filename(2)' if the uploaded file already exists in the destination folder

Tags: php, uploadify

I'm currently getting to know more with uploadify, which by the way is what I'm using on my Wordpress plugin. I got the uploading of file correctly; it's job is to upload single .pdf files only. When I tried uploading the same file twice and checked the folder where the uploaded files will be stored, I only have a single file. I guess it's being overwritten knowing the file already exists on the folder. What bugs me is that how will I change the filename of the second uploaded file(the same file) such that it will result into 'filename(2)', 'filename(3)' and so on.

Here's my code, enlighten me on where should I start configuring on my uploadify.php:

```
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $name = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = $targetFolder;
        $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

        $path = pathinfo($targetFile);

        $newTargetFile = $targetFolder.$name;

        // Validate the file type
        $fileTypes = array('pdf'); // File extensions
        $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

        if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
            // i think somewhere here , will i put something, but what's that something?
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$newTargetFile);
            echo $newTargetFile;
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid file type.';
        }
        return $newTargetFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$newTargetFile = $targetFolder.$name;
```

To this:

```
$i = 2;
list( $filename, $ext) = explode( '.', $name);
$newTargetFile = $targetFolder . $filename . '.' . $ext;
while( file_exists( $newTargetFile)) {
    $newTargetFile = $targetFolder . $filename . '(' . ++$i . ')' . '.' . $ext;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. although I put the (' . ++$i . ') on the front. Using your method, my the file will not be distinguished as such because the result is like this, filename.ext(3), making the file type unknown. BUt thanks a lot though..:)

Comment: Sure - I couldn't tell if `$name` included an extension. Glad I could help!

Comment: Actually it does include the extension.Is it possible if I can concatenate the path + filename + (++$i) + extension?

Comment: Sure, I can update my answer. One sec :) Edit: Updated - Try that :)

Comment: Hey, my man, a quick question. What will I do if the filename of the uploaded file contains '.'? Will the part that you explode still work? I tried but it exploded $name upon seeing the first '.' on the file name.

Comment: Nah it'll fail - You'd have to change the explode part to [pathinfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

function get_dup_file_name($file_name) {
    $suffix = 0;

    while (file_exists($file_name . ($suffix == 0 ? "" : "(" . $suffix . ")"))) {
        $suffix++;
    }

    return $file_name . ($suffix == 0 ? "" : "(" . $suffix . ")");
}

?>
```

Comment: can't I just add something, maybe an if condition before implementing move_uploaded_file? It may be hassle for me to use this. Just a thought.

Comment: This is a fairly simple function. The reason why you need to implement this is because you never know if there are 2, 3, 4 or a million files with the same name. This will help you handle all of this accordingly.