# Is there a way to make this function better?

Tags: php, file-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

I found the following function to get the extension of a file in a tutorial, but I think it's a bit too long. So I thought there would be a way to shorten this.

```
function getExtension($str) {
    $i = strrpos($str,".");
    if (!$i) return "";
    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str, $i+1, $l);
    return $ext;
}
```

The `$str` would be a filename.
Is there a way to shorten this function, without affecting stability and output?
I've done something like this:

```
function getExtension($str) {    
    $ext = pathinfo($str)['extension'];
    return $ext;
}
```

But that didn't work for me, but probably I did something wrong.

Comment: You could start with indenting it. :)  I have a feeling this question is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I wished that would make a difference ;) Didn't know that codereview.stackexchange.com even existed. Good thing that that exists! Thanks for notifying!

Comment: Take a look at [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: on your second example, it should be `pathinfo($str,...` instead of `pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']....`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way would be the use the [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function.

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Whoops, now I see, what a stupid mistake :O Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just remember when doing PHP: if you find yourself writing a utility function, stop. PHP already has it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Moved to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12932338/367456 - This answer will be deleted.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the `$ext = (new SplFileInfo($path))->getExtension();` syntax only works in PHP>=5.4

Comment: @DennisHaarbrink: Yes that type of de-referencing is only available in PHP >= 5.4, the SplFileInfo itself is available in PHP 5 >= 5.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
function getExtension($filename)
{
    $parts = explode('.', $filename);

    if (sizeof($parts) > 1) {
        return array_pop($parts);
    }

    return '';
}
```

Comment: I think it's worst than using `strrpos`. Arrays are slower...

Comment: True. However in this case, how long of a filename can we realisticly expect? :) Tho, @Dennis's answer is way better indeed.