# PHP file extension issue

Tags: php, file, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

How can we get file extension with any php function?

Whether there is some built-in function in php. I am using some explode function but any other exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can .......

Just Use the following code.......

Pass path of file to this PHP function and get extension.

```
    function extension($path) {
      $qpos = strpos($path, "?");

       if ($qpos!==false) $path = substr($path, 0, $qpos);

        $extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        return $extension;
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for this:

```
echo pathinfo("foo.txt", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

But rolling your own with `strrpos` is not difficult as well.

Comment: I don't recall exactly what problem I had using this function, it was long time ago, something bugging about /usr/share/file/magic, but I don't remember :/ That's why I avoid using this function. Any ideas why this function might complain about not finding that path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the [`Pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function.

```
<?php
    $path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');
     echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
     echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
     echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
     echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
/www/htdocs/inc
lib.inc.php
php //your extension
lib.inc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to get a file extension:

```
$filename = '/some/path/file.txt';
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1));
```

You can wrap it in your `Utils` class or something ;)

Comment: So why don't you use the built-in function that everyone else is referencing in their answers - do you have some secret knowledge that shows your method is better?

Comment: Not at all! I used to use pathinfo(). Might be my server setup, but time ago I started to have some issues when using that function, something about not finding the path `/usr/share/file/magic` so, when I needed to export and resize some images, I took this (substr()) approach instead of pathinfo(), but c'mon, if you don't have any issues using pathinfo, go for it. ;)