# Unable to get image extension like .jpeg

Tags: php, image, image-processing

Am uploading multiple images from single input

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="files" class="hidde fileInpu"/>
```

and i made the following code to read details of image uploading

**Full processing code**

```
  $newname = md5(rand() * time());
$file1 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][0]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][0] : null;
$file2 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][1]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][1] : null;
$file3 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][2]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][2] : null;
$file4 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][3]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][3] : null;
$file5 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][4]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][4] : null;
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $file_name = $key . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];

        $extarray = explode('.', $file_type);

        $ext = end($extarray);
// png , jpg, jpeg
        if ($file_size > 9097152000) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
        if (empty($errors) == true) {
            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if (is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name);
            } else {                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir = "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name;
                rename($file_tmp, $new_dir);
            }
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if (empty($error)) {
        echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
        echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
        echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
        echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
        echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
    }
```

**I need to display file extension of each file in `echo` and i need to skip file name insted of file name i need to store `$key`**

the above code reads image `name,size,file type, tmp name` now my problem is

```
$file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
```

this code delivers file type like `image/jpeg` **But i need to get extension** `.jpeg`

**how do i get extension in .jpeg**

and used this method after reading this topic [PHP file extension issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931296/php-file-extension-issue?lq=1) `$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)[$key];` i get error all file are in same type **how do i read each file extension**

Comment: why are you dereferencing on `pathinfo()`? just use it straight up: `$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`

Comment: And what is the purpose of the first 5 lines??

Comment: @Ghost all images are shown as`.jpg` even added `.png`

Comment: @Cheery above 5 line i use for saving file name in SQL table row

Comment: @sanojoverflow why not to prepare an array of names in the loop that you have?

Answer (score 1):

use php "pathinfo" function to get extension.

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['news_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  

$file_type = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Reference For [pathinfo](https://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Here i post full code to get extension. i have add pathinfo function to get extension

```
 <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="files" class="hidde fileInpu"/>
 <input title="" type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>


<?php
```

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
    $newname = md5(rand() * time());
    $file1 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][0]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][0] : null;
    $file2 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][1]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][1] : null;
    $file3 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][2]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][2] : null;
    $file4 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][3]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][3] : null;
    $file5 = isset($_FILES['files']['name'][4]) ? $_FILES['files']['name'][4] : null;

        $errors = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $file_name = $key . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            echo $file_name;
            echo $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
            die;
            //$extarray = explode('.', $file_type);

          //  $ext = end($extarray);
            // png , jpg, jpeg
            if ($file_size > 9097152000) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }
            $desired_dir = "user_data/";
            if (empty($errors) == true) {
                if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
                }
                if (is_dir("$desired_dir/" . $file_name) == false) {
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name);
                } else {                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                    $new_dir = "$desired_dir/" . $newname . $file_name;
                    rename($file_tmp, $new_dir);
                }
            } else {
                print_r($errors);
            }
        }
        if (empty($error)) {
            echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
            echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
            echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
            echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
            echo "FILE : $newname.$ext<br>";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: which line should i use this line does't have `$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['news_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` any link

Comment: Check my updated answer.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_pathinfo.asp

Comment: matheta  check my question i have posted my entire processing code above

Comment: thats perfect but only one request at end of code in made 5`echo` there i want to display`$file1.$ext1``$file2.$ext2``$file3.$ext3``$file4.$ext4``$file5.$ext5`

Comment: i need to display every file name

Answer (score 0):

try using this example

```
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];

    $extarray=explode('.',$file_type); 

    $ext=end($extarray);
// png , jpg, jpeg
```

Comment: i get error `Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\Users\logon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\locahost test\poster\process\mobile\mobileprocessing.php on line 18`

Comment: @sanojoverflow this is not an actual error, but the result of `explode` should be assigned to the temporary variable and this variable used in `end` function. But `pathinfo` should work fine, you do not need these manipulations.

Comment: @Cheery but image names are not processed to sql

Comment: @manojdhiman check my question i have posted my entire processing code above