# How to extract part of the path and the ending file name with Regex?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

I need to build an associative array with the plugin name and the language file it uses in the following sequence:

```
/whatever/path/length/public_html/wp-content/plugins/adminimize/languages/adminimize-en_US.mo
/whatever/path/length/public_html/wp-content/plugins/audio-tube/lang/atp-en_US.mo
/whatever/path/length/public_html/wp-content/languages/en_US.mo
/whatever/path/length/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/languages/en_US.mo
```

Those are the language files WordPress is loading.
They are all inside `/wp-content/`, but with variable server paths.
I'm looking only for those inside the plugins folder, grab the plugin folder name and the filename.

Hipothetical case in PHP, where **`reg_extract_*`** functions are the parts I'm missing:

```php
$plugins = array();

foreach( $big_array as $item ) 
{
    $folder = reg_extract_folder( $item );
    if( 'plugin' == $folder ) 
    {
        // "folder-name-after-plugins-folder"
        $plugin_name = reg_extract_pname( $item ); 

        // "ending-mo-file.mo"
        $file_name = reg_extract_fname( $item ); 

        $plugins[] = array( 'name' => $plugin_name, 'file' => $file_name );
    }
}
```

[update]

Ok, so I was missing quite a basic function, `pathinfo`... :/

No problem to detect if `/plugins/` is contained in the array.

But what about the plugin folder name?

Comment: where is the reg_extract_folder() function?

Comment: @Dagon, sorry, I didn't specify that those were the functions I don't have... Updating question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = '/whatever/path/length/public_html/wp-content/plugins/adminimize/languages/adminimize-en_US.mo';
preg_match('/plugins\/([^\/]+?)\/(?:[^\/]+\/)?(.+)/', $path, $matches);
$dir = $matches[1];
$filename = $matches[2];
```

this would store adminize in $dir and adminimize-en_US.mo in $filename

Comment: Tested the code but doesn't outputs a result. thx

Comment: Did you try the latest iteration? You can `print_r($matches);` to verify they are correct. I've verified this works.

Comment: Sooorry, I was testing inside an existent function. Just re-run and it does the job, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This example will get all the files within a folder, and display all the information about the file path.

```
<?php

foreach(glob("/path/tofiles/*.*") as $file){
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    echo $info['dirname'], "\n";
    echo $info['basename'], "\n";
    echo $info['extension'], "\n";
    echo $info['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that... promise not to forget `pathinfo` never again... Unfortunately, it doesn't grab all the info I need. Updated the Q.