# Shortest way to get the filename extension with PHP

Tags: php, file-extension

I've seen alot of functions which handle the retrival of an extension of a particular filename. I, myself, always use this solution of mine:

```
function extension( $filename = __FILE__ ) {
    $parts = explode('.', $filename);
    return (strtolower($parts[(sizeof($parts) - 1)]));
}

echo extension();              // php
echo extension('.htaccess');   // htaccess
echo extension('htaccess');    // htaccess
echo extension('index.php');   // php
```

Is that the best and the fastest approach?

Comment: pathinfo() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php with PATHINFO_EXTENSION

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

I'll go ahead and say that it is not the best approach, and I suspect it isn't fastest either. The canonical way is using [`pathinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

The problem with using `explode` is that you're creating an array, which necessarily takes up more memory (even if it is a trivial amount) which almost always leads to a decrease in speed. If you really want to go with a home-cooked non-canonical way, I suggest [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php):

```
function get_extension($file)
{
    $pos = strrpos($file, '.');
    // for condition when strrpos returns FALSE on failure.
    if($pos !== FALSE) return substr($file, $pos);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$file =  pathinfo('index.php');
echo $file['extension']; // 'php'
```

Answer (score 1):

That works, one thing i would change is your return:

```
return strtolower(end($parts));
```

I agree pathinfo is probably the better way I was just improving your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = "filename.php.jpg.exe";
echo substr($file, strrpos($file, "."));//.exe
```

Comment: `substr($file, strrpos($file, ".")+1);` for removing dot

Comment: isn't my function a bit easier... :)

Comment: one up for you, for your effort! :)