# Validate font file in PHP

Tags: php, validation, fonts

How can I make sure that the supplied file - font(TrueType)? File path may be specified with custom extension(non `.ttf`).

I'm confused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php

Comment: it's not. I also pointed out - file can have any extension(non `ttf`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: [finfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

For example:

```
$fileName = 'file.ext';
$mimeTypes = array('font/ttf','font/truetype');
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $fileName);
if(in_array($mime, $mimeTypes)){
    echo 'font file';
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

You must check `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE`.