# The word "Array" Added to every file name when trying to save an image - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, upload, image-uploading

Im getting an image from my app to this php code:

```
<?php 

$target = "upload/"; 
$name="checks";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded'].$name); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "yes";
} 
else {
echo "no";
}
?>
```

The problem is that every name of a picture that I upload starts with "Array".

for example, `$name` is now "checks", so the filename would be "Arraychecks".

Why is this happening?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Please stop adding further questions into the original one as soon as you get the previous ones answered. Stack Overflow aims to be a knowledge base in Q&A format, not a free consulting service. You should use the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button or, even better, search first among the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['uploaded']` is an array.

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                )

        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

You're probably looking for `$_FILES['uploaded']['name']`

Comment: Im sorry, you are right. My real question is how can I change the name of the file Im getting before saving it, so there wont be collusions?

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = $_FILES['checks']['name'];
$fileElementName = 'checks';
$path = 'upload/'; 
$location = $path . $_FILES['checks']['name']; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['checks']['tmp_name'], $location);
```

now in your insert query use $name

Comment: $name= here take whatever name you like to insert

Answer (score 1):

Getting the word `Array` is a typical symptom of casting an array to string:

```
$data = array(10, 20, 30);
var_dump( (string)$data );
// Notice: Array to string conversion
// string(5) "Array"
```

It's obvious from your code that `$_FILES['uploaded']` is an array because you do this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))
```

... so this can't be right:

```
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded'].$name);
```

Perhaps you had this in mind:

```
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name'].$name);
```

Comment: yes. that is what I had in my mind. Ty! but can you also tell me how can I add the extantion to the filename? because right now the image saves it without it.

Comment: [How to extract a file extension in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)