# Known image file name on internet host folder . . . unknown file extension. . . How to extract

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP page I built to help build eBay listing templates.  I have a folder on my hosting account which stores 100's of logos of products I sell.  I know the file names but not the file type (jpg, gif, png, etc).  I just switched from hosting that did not care about extensions to hosting that does.  Is there away for me to use javascript or PHP to automatically ascertain the file extension?  I use a form to input the file name and want the output to include the file name with extension.

Thanks in advance,

Trevor

Comment: Did you have a look [**`here`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)?

Comment: Show us the code you use currently so we can help identify where the issue exists.

Comment: This code is where I ask for the file name for the logo on an html page: `<p>Logo 1: <input name="e" value="" type="text" size="15" maxlength="30" />`  This is the code on the php page where the results are echoed: `if(!empty($e)) { echo '<img src="gbamedical.com/ebayimg/logos/'.$e.'"';; };` I need to know how to dynamically add the extension.