# How to dynamically determine unknown file extension from file in web folder

Tags: php

I have a page using forms to help build listing templates for eBay.  I have a folder where I have hundreds of logos stored.  I know the logo names but not their extensions. . . .  I have to test each potential (jpg, jpeg, gif, png, etc.) until I guess right.  Here is an example code for the web form:

```
<form action="extension_test2.php" method="post">
 <p>Logo: <input name="e" value="" type="text" size="15" maxlength="30" /><p>
<input name="Submit" type="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and the form's result:

```
<?

$e =$_POST['e'];

if(!empty($e)) {
echo '<img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/ebayimg/logos/'.$e.'">';
};

?>
```

Here is a link to the example:  http://www.gbamedical.com/extension_test.php  Use "olympus.jpg" for test.

I am looking for code that can determine the file type and dynamically add the extension.  Can it be done?

I asked the question in a different, apparently confusing way here: [Known image file name on internet host folder . . . unknown file extension. . . How to extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589571/known-image-file-name-on-internet-host-folder-unknown-file-extension) The answer I received showed code (The code worked with outside image examples given but doesn't work with images hosted on my server) that does not require the extension to echo the image. . ..  but, I need the extension to be echoed as well because I ultimately copy the code of the resulting html page in an eBay page.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question, [Known image file name on internet host folder . . . unknown file extension. . . How to extract](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589571/known-image-file-name-on-internet-host-folder-unknown-file-extension)

Comment: I asked this question in a different, apparently confusing way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589571/known-image-file-name-on-internet-host-folder-unknown-file-extension The answer I received showed code (The code worked with outside image examples given but doesn't work with images hosted on my server) that does not require the extension to echo the image. . ..  but, I need the extension to be echoed as well because I ultimately copy the code of the resulting html page in an eBay page.