# File upload in php throwing error for file type and file size though its within the defined rules

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am facing a problem while uploading file to mysql using php. the script works for almost everyone but it dosen't work from couple of machines and throwing an error which is set by me for file type and file size.

```
<?php 
include ('config.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);  //300 sec =5min

//csv file type check
$csv_mimetypes = array(
'text/csv',    
'application/csv',
'text/comma-separated-values',
'application/excel',
'application/vnd.ms-excel',
'application/vnd.msexcel',    
);
$msg="";
$maxsize    = 2097152;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Validate if csv file type as specified in array and check file size must not exceed 2MB
  if ((in_array($_FILES['filename']['type'], $csv_mimetypes)) && ($_FILES['filename']['size'] < $maxsize)){

       if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] . "</h1>";
        }

     $csv_file=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
     $handle = fopen($csv_file, "r");

     $i=0;
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        if($i>0){
          $import=mysql_query("insert statement");
        }
          $i=1;  
      }      
   $msg="Uploaded Successfully";   
  } else {
$msg="Something went wrong . Please check the file type and FileSize.";   
  }
 }
?>
```

this script for upload file is running fine but from couple of machine while uploading it is throwing error `"Something went wrong . Please check the file type and FileSize."` though it meets the file type and file size.

Comment: dump the file's properties so we can know what is going on with it. Also... you should use separated if conditions so you can say which part of it failed, "Something went wrong in one of the x cases we checked, you must guess which case failed." is an awful error handling.

Comment: It could be either of your conditions failing.  Are you sure it's not the other?

Comment: what other checking need to be given to see more clearly where it is happening.

Comment: @Jonast92 yes i couldn't find any other possible cases to check with.therefore only checked with file type and file size.what other cases needs to be checked here?

Comment: Something went wrong .... why do you create an error-message, that tells nothing about the error itself ;)

Comment: something went wrong please check the file type and file size is the error.
i found that checking with $_FILES['filename']['type'] is not convenient for uploading images type rather used exif_imagetype($_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']); is there anything that checks csv file type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this line

```
//Validate if csv file type as specified in array and check file size must not exceed 2MB
if ((in_array($_FILES['filename']['type'], $csv_mimetypes)) && ($_FILES['filename']['size'] < $maxsize)){
```

changed to:-

```
$type = explode('.',$_FILES['filename']['name']);
if((strtolower(end($type)) == 'csv') && ($_FILES['filename']['size']< $maxsize)) {
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You're not suppose to find more cases to check, you need to separate them.

```
if(in_array($_FILES['filename']['type'], $csv_mimetypes)) && ($_FILES['filename']['size'] < $maxsize)
{
    // Success, yay for me!
}
else
{
    // You have no idea what went wrong.
}
```

Separate the logic, i.e.

```
$validType = in_array($_FILES['filename']['type'], $csv_mimetypes);
$validSize = $_FILES['filename']['size'] < $maxsize;
```

Now you can check specifically what went wrong.

```
if(!$validType)
{
    $msg .= "The type is invalid.";
}
if(!$validSize)
{
    $msg .= "The size is invalid.";
}
```

You should consider [changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php) the way you check for the file's type, e.g. using [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$validType = in_array($ext, $extensions);
```

Where `$extensions` is an predefined array from you.

Whatever is going wrong, you must separate the error handling logic.