# Javascript validate file input name

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I currently having a problem to validate the file name that user upload into the file input. I already had the validation on file extension, but when user trying to upload a file name example `1.hello.jpg`, for my JavaScript validation code it was look okay as it was `jpg` extension. But in my PHP part my validation for the file extension does not recognize it as I'm using explode function to validate the file extension.

Is there anyway to validate the special character of the file in client side before submitted to my server side? Thanks

Here are my validation on client side:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

            function checkDisabled(yourSubmitButton){


              //No 1 file input validation  
              var res_field = document.getElementById('uploaded_file').value; 
              var extension = res_field.substr(res_field.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
              var allowedExtensions = ['jpg','JPG','bmp','BMP','png','PNG','jpeg','JPEG'];

              if(document.getElementById('bannerName').value.length !=0){
                  //File input extension validation
                  if (res_field.length > 0)
                 {
                      if (allowedExtensions.indexOf(extension) !== -1) 
                         {
                           yourSubmitButton.disabled = false;
                            return;
                         }
                }
              }



                // If we have made it here, disable it
                yourSubmitButton.disabled = true;

              };
              </script>
```

Here are my php code for validate the extension:

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "JPEG","png","PNG","bmp","BMP",'JPG','jpeg');
    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
            $bName = $_POST['bannerName'];
            $bDescription = $_POST['bannerDescription'];
            $bK = $_POST['bannerK'];
            $bKe = $_POST['bannerKe'];
            $bS= $_POST['bannerS'];

            if(strlen($name))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                    {

                        ...........
                    }
                }
```

Comment: 1.hello.jpg has two dots, by which you are trying to explode, so when exploding $ext has value hello which is invalid.

Comment: What if i uploaded a file `something.jpg.php` from what i'm reading this would upload and i could then execute my own server-side code on your server giving me access to pretty much everything and anything...

Comment: @newtojs
What I understand from your statement, php file is unable to submit it to my server because my java script validation is only allowed image file

Comment: @sanjay 
Based on your knowledge which is the best solution to validate the file name and extension? Thanks

Comment: @MarcusTan Javascript is client-side and can be changed using the browser console. Example `allowedExtensions.push('php');`

Comment: @Marcus Tan try the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solve it by using split function on javascript.

Here is my code:

```
//Check for dot that is not more than 1
            var checkStr = 0;
            var str = document.getElementById('uploaded_file').value;
            var res = str.split(".");

            for(var i = 0 ; i <= res.length;i++){
                checkStr++;
            }

            if(checkStr>3){

                alert(str+' invalid filename detected. \n\n Please rename your file.');
                return false;
            }
```

For those beginner like me can refer to that, as i'm trying to split the filename that browser into the file input. If the array after split function is more than 3 then prompt out error.

Example :

1. -1.hello.jpg (Error)
2. -1_hello.jpg (Success)

Thanks for all the help. Much Appreciate

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP  use `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` to get the file extension :

```
$ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

For more info , check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php).

Comment: what is it outputting ?

Comment: If I try 1.dscksodjh.jpg it also don't allow me to insert into my database

Comment: what are you trying to insert , Name or the File

Comment: When user browse the file and wanted to submit

Answer (score 1):

Try access the below value

```
$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]
```

and validate in server side.

Comment: Wait me have a try and get back to u

Comment: How can i do the validation on client side?

Comment: return filename.split('.').pop();