# get file name without extension in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have used `Input::file('upfile')->getClientOriginalName()` to retrieve name of uploaded file but gives name with extension like `qwe.jpg`.How do I get name without extension like `qwe` in laravel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get (extract) a file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-do-i-get-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 93):

Laravel uses Symfony `UploadedFile` component that will be returned by `Input::file()` method.

It hasn't got any method to retrive file name, so you can use php native function `pathinfo()`:

```
pathinfo(Input::file('upfile')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Comment: If there is $request, instead of Input model, the code should as '$filename = pathinfo($request->file('import_file')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);'

Answer (score 65):

You could try this

```
$file = Input::file('upfile')->getClientOriginalName();

$filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

echo $filename . ' ' . $extension; // 'qwe jpg'
```

Answer (score 18):

In Laravel 5.2

Use Request and it's already present in the app file in the aliases array

To retrieve original file name

```
$request->file('upfile')->getClientOriginalName();
```

To get file name without extension

```
basename($request->file('upfile')->getClientOriginalName(), '.'.$request->file('upfile')->getClientOriginalExtension());
```

Answer (score 16):

This one is pretty clean:

```
  $fileName = pathinfo($fullFileName)['filename'];
```

Equivalent to:

```
  $fileName = pathinfo($fullFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

https://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 11):

here you need to call php PATHINFO_FILENAME

```
$file = $request->file('fileupload')->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName = pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
dd($fileName);
```

Answer (score 8):

In Laravel 7 the Fluent Strings were introduced which allows to do this in an extremely elegant way.

The `basename` method will return the trailing name component of the given string:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$string = Str::of('/foo/bar/baz.jpg')->basename();

// 'baz.jpg'
```

If needed, you may provide an "extension" that will be removed from the trailing component:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$string = Str::of('/foo/bar/baz.jpg')->basename('.jpg');

// 'baz'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code too.

```
    if ($request->hasfile('filename')) {
        $image = $request->filename;
        $namewithextension = $image->getClientOriginalName(); //Name with extension 'filename.jpg'
        $name = explode('.', $namewithextension)[0]; // Filename 'filename'
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //Extension 'jpg'
        $uploadname = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $image->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', $uploadname);
    }
```

Comment: If my file name is "natural.picture.png", then is it work?

Comment: I tested your succession. It works fine. The code generating new name and saving the extension correctly. I'm using Laravel 5.7 by the way.

Comment: i know this old tread, but that will failed with `natural.picture.png` the `name` will be return natural, and in the end this saving the file using `time()`

Answer (score 3):

I use this code and work in my Laravel 5.2.*

```
$file=$request->file('imagefile');
$imgrealpath= $file->getRealPath(); 
$nameonly=preg_replace('/\..+$/', '', $file->getClientOriginalName());
$fullname=$nameonly.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the file name using getClientOriginalName(); then use the explode function to get the name and the image format as shown below:

`$image=Input::file('image');
$fullName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
$name=explode('.',$fullName)[0];`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    $fullName = Input::file('image')->getClientOrginalName();
    $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOrginalExtension();
    $onlyName = explode('.'.$extension,$fullName);
```

Or This:

```
    $fullName = Input::file('image')->getClientOrginalName();
    $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOrginalExtension();

    $fullNameLenght = strlen($fullName);
    $extensionLenght = strlen($extension);
    $nameLength = $fullNameLenght - ($extensionLength + 1);
    $onlyName = strpos($fullName, 0, $nameLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\..+$/', '', 'qwe.jpg')
```

or

```
explode('.', 'qwe.jpg')[0]
```

Comment: Just a small notice, what about .tar.gz files with your solution? ;)

Comment: the best for cleaness, but works in 90% of cases, it depends on the situation if it could be a correct option

Answer (score 1):

Using laravel Str helper:

```php
$title = \Illuminate\Support\Str::beforeLast($file->getClientOriginalName(), ".{$file->getClientOriginalExtension()}")
```

Using PHP standard method:

```php
$title = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), \PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score -6):

you can use this

```
Input::file('upfile')->getClientOriginalExtension()
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? The OP asked for the file name without the extension, calling `getClientOriginalExtension` returns the extension only....

Comment: this is how you can get it, missed 2nd line earlier

$ext = Input::file('upfile')->getClientOriginalExtension();
echo basename($path, '.'.$ext);

Comment: Please edit your answer such that it contains all relevant information, this includes both the code and a short explanation about the code

Comment: this is how you can get it, missed 2nd line earlier 
    `$ext = Input::file('upfile')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    echo basename($path, '.'.$ext);`

Comment: Still, please edit your answer and add all relevant information there, not to the comment section

Comment: `getClientOriginalExtension()` will only return the file extension not the filename.