# How to make unique name for image during upload in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image, concatenation, laravel-5.5

I am using laravel 5.5 and uploading image.
My code is generating name in wrong way.

```
 $image_icon = $request->file('image_icon');
 $data['image'] = $image_icon->getClientOriginalName().'.'.time();
 $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
 $image_icon->move($destinationPath, $data['image']);
```

Output name of image is like : **heart.png.1544074437**

Name should be : **heart1544074437.png**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one by using [pathinfo](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_pathinfo.asp) function

extract file name ..

```
$fileName = pathinfo($image_icon->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

extract extenstion

```
$extension = pathinfo($image_icon->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

create new file name.

```
$fullFileName = $fileName."-".time().$image_icon->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

for more information see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776197/get-file-name-without-extension-in-laravel/46557656)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

> pathinfo — Returns information about a file path
>
> path
>   The path to be parsed.
>
> options If present, specifies a specific element to be returned; one
>   of PATHINFO_DIRNAME, PATHINFO_BASENAME, PATHINFO_EXTENSION or
>   PATHINFO_FILENAME.
>
> If options is not specified, returns all available elements.

```
$image_icon = $request->file('image_icon')->getClientOriginalName();

$filename = pathinfo($image_icon, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($image_icon, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data['image'] = $filename.time().'.'.$extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to do this:

```
$image = explode(".", $image_icon);
$image_name = $image[0];
$image_extension = array_slice($image , -1, 1);

$data['image'] = $image_name.time().'.'.$image_extension[0];
```

I hope this will be helpful and easy solution to your problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $imgName = md5(str_random(30).time().'_'.$request->file('image_icon')).'.'.$request->file('image_icon')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Answer (score 0):

Above code need minor improvement as follows :

```
$image_icon = $request->file('image_icon');

$fileName = pathinfo($image_icon->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

$extension = pathinfo($image_icon->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$data['image'] = $image_icon->getClientOriginalName().time().'.'.$extension;
```

I have not tested this code snippet, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use laravel out of the box solution for Upload:

```
$request->photo->store('images');
```

For more check here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#files

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working fine for me.

```
// extract file name ..

        $fileName = pathinfo($fileupload_dt->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        
        // extract extenstion

        $extension = pathinfo($fileupload_dt->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        
        // create new file name.

        $imageName = $fileName."-".time().".".$fileupload_dt->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $uploadPath = 'public/ArchiveImg/img';
        $fileupload_dt->move($uploadPath,$imageName);
        $imageUrl = $uploadPath.$imageName;
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is unique name also in the file name

```
$file= $request->file('image');
$filename= date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move(public_path('storage/products'), $filename);
```