# SQL : get substring from one column and inserting it into other column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

First column contains image files names:

```
abcd.jpg
abcdef.png
...
abcdjs.xyz
```

I want to make another column which contains extensions of these image files:

```
jpg
png
... 
xyz
```

But some image files are named like `ab.gefs.jpg`.

I am not able to take the `string` after the last (.) dot.

Comment: See [*How to extract a file extension in PHP?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php).

Comment: Are all filenames guaranteed to have an extension?

Comment: You're trying to do this in php or mysql?

Comment: yes @MonkeyZeus

Comment: in mysql @PhiterFernandes

Comment: i know how to do it in php but i wanna know how to do it in mysql @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: The regex for finding everything after the final period `.` is `[^.]+$`. So try it out at http://regexr.com/

Comment: mysql doesn't support capturing groups so regex seems useless here: it's either matched or not matched in mysql

Comment: @BorysZibrov I did not know that, good catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reverse the file name, so that extension comes first and reversed, then locate the first dot, then cut everything before the dot -- that would be the reversed extension --, then reverse again:

```
UPDATE some_table t1, some_table t2
SET t1.some_column = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t2.filename) FROM 1 FOR LOCATE('.', REVERSE(t2.filename))))
WHERE t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key;
```

Comment: I like this answer but based on OP's question this should probably be an update statement.

Comment: thanks, I updated my answer to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT INTO`

Comment: @Azhar, I actually didn't know about the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function, seems like that's a better way to do that : )

Comment: All of that `REVERSE`ing made my head spin! ;-)

Comment: ha! you bet :-)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function is pretty much tailor made for what you're trying to do:

```
> select substring_index( 'foo.png', '.', -1 );
+---------------------------------------+
| substring_index( 'foo.png', '.', -1 ) |
+---------------------------------------+
| png                                   |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

> select substring_index( 'foo.bar.jpg', '.', -1 );
+-------------------------------------------+
| substring_index( 'foo.bar.jpg', '.', -1 ) |
+-------------------------------------------+
| jpg                                       |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yeah, this seems like much better way than reversing a string 2 times :) thanks, @ardavey