# PHP Get full extension of for example index.twig.php

Tags: php

I have a string: `index.twig.php`
and I need to get: `twig.php`
from it. I tried to use `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`
but it only gives me `php` I need everything from the first dot.

Comment: substr(strpos($path, "."))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function that does exactly that:

```
$ext = strstr($filename, '.');
```

You can trim the leading dot if you don't want it:

```
$ext = ltrim($ext, '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`join()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php), [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) php functions :

#### i.e. :

```
$s = "index.twig.php";
echo join('.', array_slice(explode('.', $s), -2));
```

#### Output :

> twig.php

#### Explanation :

`expolde()` will create an array by spliting the string on every ".".

`array_slice()` will slice the array to keep last two elements only.

`join()` will concatenate the result by "." in a new string.

---

Since other answers don't take care if the filename contains additional dots (i.e. "some.file.name.twig.php"), this solution will keep last two items only to isolate the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `explode` to do it.

```
$string = 'index.twig.php';
list($filename, $extension) = explode('.', $string, 2);
```