# PHP list file with exception

Tags: php, readdir, opendir

I have made a PHP page which shows a list of files in one folder. Now that I don't want some one to access this folder directly, I plan to add a PHP script which redirects to index.php. Simply I don't want this file to appear in the list

Can I add exception to this extension only? or any better idea for that?

```
if ($handle = opendir('manual')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
           if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
               echo "<a href='manual/$entry' target='_blank'>$entry</><br>";
           }
     }
     closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: You can add a `.htaccess` rule inside the `manual` folder which will prevent access to that directory -- but then all your links the above code outputs will be broken.  In which case, instead of referring to 'manual/$entry'  call another file like `foo.php?file=$entry` which foo.php is responsible for getting the contents of `$entry`.  This overall is really sloppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your index.php file to be displayed in this list then simply use an `if` statement.

```
if ($handle = opendir('manual')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
           if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
               if($entry!='index.php') // Go ahead only if the file is not index.php
                   echo "<a href='manual/$entry' target='_blank'>$entry</a><br>";
           }
     }
     closedir($handle);
}
```

And, if you want to hide all the php files, then you can use `preg_match`:

```
if ($handle = opendir('manual')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
           if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
               if (!preg_match('/.php/', $entry)) // Go ahead only if the file is not having .php as it's extension
                   echo "<a href='manual/$entry' target='_blank'>$entry</a><br>";
           }
     }
     closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: sure this work, but can i just like prevent all .php file to appear?

Comment: You could use `preg_match()`, or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php to get the extension and compare that.

Comment: yeah you can use `preg_match`. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a flag variable to identify the status of visitor,if has no the variable,let he redirect. Usually we use session the global variable to do the work