# adding file extension when uploading file php

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file to a directory, ad rename it in the process. The file is uploaded to the directory, but without the file extension, i.e. 123456789. is uploaded.

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}


else{
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"]);
$newfilename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . '.' .end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . 
$newfilename);  
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'files/' . 
$newfilename));{
echo "File uploaded successfully!!";
}
```

I have also tried the following to no avail:

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}



else{
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"]);
$extension = pathinfo($temp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newfilename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . '.' .$extension;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . 
$newfilename);  
}



if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'files/' . 
$newfilename));{
echo "File uploaded successfully!!";
}
```

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong? Everything else works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

Comment: Ok, fine plan. Thumbs up. Go. _(or did you have any question here?)_

Comment: Don't `explode()` first.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have asked a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had decalred the directory as "uploads" in one part of the code, and "files" in another. Same with "file" and "file to upload". Silly mistake.

I also removed explode and added line of code suggested by GentlemanMax.

Solution:

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}


else{  
$ext = pathinfo(($_FILES["file"]["name"]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newfilename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . 
$newfilename);  
}


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'files/' . 
$newfilename));{
echo "File uploaded successfully!!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`pathinfo()` takes a string as its first parameter, you are passing it an array. Try changing:

```
$extension = pathinfo($temp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

to

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I am still getting a file without an extension. I really dont think it is the case, but could it be something to do with the following code on the button press:

Comment: function uploadFile() {
     if ($("#file_to_upload").val() != "") {
         var file_data = $('#file_to_upload').prop('files')[0];
         var form_data = new FormData();

         form_data.append('file', file_data);

       and then ajax call....

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"]);
$extension = pathinfo($temp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

$temp becomes an array and pathinfo() expects a string. You should see this in your error log. Instead, do this:

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```