# Using PHP strpos() function inside and if loop won't work as expected?

Tags: php, loops, strpos

I have a string of text that is the name of a file, and I want to show it only if the name of the file does not contain an image extension.

This are the string structures:

```
this-file-1.jpg
other_file.pdf
and-yet_another--file.zip
and-another-one.png
```

I've tried:

```
if ( strpos($value, 'jpg') === FALSE) {
    echo $mostrarArchivos;
}
```

And it does work, but when I try this it doesn't:

```
if ( strpos($value, 'jpg') === FALSE ||
    strpos($value, 'jpeg') === FALSE ||
    strpos($value, 'png') === FALSE ||
    strpos($value, 'gif') === FALSE
) {
    echo $mostrarArchivos;
}
```

In the sense that it does show the string with the filename, even if the string says `whatever.jpg`

I do realizse that this should be done differently, so any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: You want to use `&&` (and), not `||` (or). There are [far more solid ways to get a file's extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-getextract-a-file-extension-in-php), btw. Yours will fail if "jpg" or another one is present in the actual name.

Comment: I assume your string will contain only one filename, is that correct?

Comment: I would like to know why I've been downvoted. I would like to know in order to improve my question next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a much simpler and more flexible solution, as you can add or remove extension easily to the `$invalid` array any time you like. This will also make sure you are testing the actual extension as well rather than a character sequence in the filename part that happens to match the extensions you want to ignore.

```
$invalid = ['jpg','gif','png'];

$filename = 'hello_world.png';

if ( ! in_array(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $invalid) ) {
    echo 'VALID EXTN ' . $filename . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'INVALID EXTN '  . $filename . PHP_EOL;
}
```