# check file format before upload in php

Tags: php

```
       $ID="JHON";
       $uploaddir = './files/';
       $name=$ID."_".jpg";
       $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$name;
       $size=filesize($_FILES['up_file']['tmp_name']);
       $size=$size/1024;
    
       $file_ = explode(".",$uploadfile);
       // var file_= file.name.split(".");
       // if(file_[1]=="png" || file_[1]=="jpeg" || file_[1]=="jpg" || file_[1]=="doc" || 
       // file_[1]=="docx" || file_[1]=="pdf")  
       {
       if($size<1024)
       {
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['up_file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
       }
       }
```

Hello.
It is upload a file.$name saved files in jpg. But how can I do, check the file is png,jpg,doc,docx,pddf.. etc, and upload in the right format?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-do-i-get-a-file-extension-in-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a file extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-do-i-get-a-file-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use getimagesize() to get the mimetype,

```
$file = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$mimeType = $file['mime']; 
$allowedMimeTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png',];
if(in_array($mimeType, $allowedMimeTypes, false){
 // allowed, do something 
}else{
 // mimetype not allowed
 }
```