# 500 Internal Server Error Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

Hello i got strange error, normaly it's works on xampp, but when i setup it on host i'ts give me error that Only variables should be passed by reference, but i don't get it why, can you guy's help me please.

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./extensions");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
if (in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $file))), array('php'))) {
    include $file;
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It may  be PHP version related, run `php --version` on both sever and Xamp.

Comment: Any function needing a reference can't use the return from another function - `array_pop` is one of them.

Comment: You also might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-do-i-get-a-file-extension-in-php is an alternative (if you are just extracting the file extension).

Comment: Thank you both for your help, it was php version issue, Soloved :) Changing to version 7 and up fix this issue.